# KeyError with dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following

```
a = {'afaf178a0a3e4f91812d36a3c3289dbd': {'profile_id': 'afaf178a0a3e4f91812d36a3c3289dbd', 'cute_name': 'Watermelon'}, 'cd1800ef65ea4ac7a65effed5ed420d0': {'profile_id': 'cd1800ef65ea4ac7a65effed5ed420d0', 'cute_name': 'Peach'}, 'b673d818a57f4cdeb549c0cbe152ed51': {'profile_id': 'b673d818a57f4cdeb549c0cbe152ed51', 'cute_name': 'Papaya'}}
```

When trying to access it using `a[0]` I get a KeyError. Why is this?

Comment: use `a[a.keys()[0]]`

Comment: What are you expecting to get with `a[0]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dictionary has keys:

```
>>> a.keys()
['b673d818a57f4cdeb549c0cbe152ed51', 'afaf178a0a3e4f91812d36a3c3289dbd', 'cd1800ef65ea4ac7a65effed5ed420d0']
```

You should use one of those to access the values. Otherwise you may iterate over keys with:

```
for k in a.keys() :
    pass # put something here
```

Or you may iterate over the values:

```
for v in a.values() :
    pass # put something here
```

Or you may iterate over both:

```
for k,v in a.items() :
    pass # put something here
```

Answer (score 0):

Python raises a `KeyError` whenever a `dict()` object is requested and the key is not in the dictionary.

Using the dictionary in your post as an example:

```
>>> a.keys()
dict_keys(['afaf178a0a3e4f91812d36a3c3289dbd', 'cd1800ef65ea4ac7a65effed5ed420d0', 'b673d818a57f4cdeb549c0cbe152ed51'])
```

`0` is not in the dictionary you provided, hence the `KeyError`.